# Why is Realtime Database update sometimes delayed by the burst of token renewal?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-realtime-database

In a Node.js background app that run periodically to write to Firebase Realtime Database from App Engine, sometimes I encountered a huge delay that can take up almost a minute.  The code that perform the write operations is just simply:

```
await ref.update(updates);
```

The code has been completed on-time, but somehow the process wasn't completed yet.  Curious, I added `enableLogging(true)` to enable verbose logging.  I found that when the delay happened, there is a lot of lines that looks like:

```
2021-01-18 01:25:17.512 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: {"r":1525,"a":"gauth","b":{"cred":"..."}}
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:17.515 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: Auth token refreshed
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:17.515 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: {"r":1526,"a":"gauth","b":{"cred":"..."}}
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:17.517 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: Auth token refreshed
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:17.517 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: {"r":1527,"a":"gauth","b":{"cred":"..."}}
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:17.521 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: Auth token refreshed
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:17.521 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: {"r":1528,"a":"gauth","b":{"cred":"..."}}
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:17.523 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: Auth token refreshed
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:17.523 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: {"r":1529,"a":"gauth","b":{"cred":"..."}}
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:17.524 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: Auth token refreshed
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:17.525 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: {"r":1530,"a":"gauth","b":{"cred":"..."}}
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:17.527 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: Auth token refreshed
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:17.527 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: {"r":1531,"a":"gauth","b":{"cred":"..."}}
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:17.530 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: Auth token refreshed
...
2021-01-18 01:25:38.705 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: from server: {"r":1525,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{"auth":null,"expires":1610911538}}}
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:38.812 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: from server: {"r":1526,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{"auth":null,"expires":1610911538}}}
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:38.880 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: from server: {"r":1527,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{"auth":null,"expires":1610911538}}}
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:38.940 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: from server: {"r":1528,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{"auth":null,"expires":1610911538}}}
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:39.068 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: from server: {"r":1529,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{"auth":null,"expires":1610911538}}}
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:39.112 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: from server: {"r":1530,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{"auth":null,"expires":1610911539}}}
Default
2021-01-18 01:25:39.213 WIT
[Realtime Database] p:0: from server: {"r":1531,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{"auth":null,"expires":1610911539}}}
```

Looks like these lines are refreshing auth token, but they're done so many times in such a short time and the write operation is pending until these operations are done.  I'm using default credential from App Engine.

Looking at the Firebase Admin SDK source code at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/src/firebase-app.ts#L136, the token should be renewed every minutes from 4 minutes before the token expires.  What would have caused this lot of "Auth token refreshed" logs?

The App Engine consists of several instances that uses the same service account to perform Firebase operations.
Each instance have dynamic `setInterval()` operations and lot of `setImmediate()` to prevent event loop to be blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved after I changed the authentication from application default credentials to dedicated service account.